# Problem calling method from another class

Tags: java

My program only runs "correctly" if i add the three Scanners in main but if i delete them, i get "cannot resolve symbol fnum, snum and total" error. How can i call this method from the CalculatorClass, from main?

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



    Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    NameInputClass nameInputClassObject = new NameInputClass();
    System.out.println("Hello! Please enter your name");
    String name = nameInput.nextLine();
    nameInputClassObject.nameInput(name);

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fnum = input1.nextInt();
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int snum = input1.nextInt();
    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = input1.nextInt();
    CalculatorClass calculatorClassObject = new CalculatorClass();
    calculatorClassObject.calcInput(snum,fnum,total);


public class NameInputClass {
public static void nameInput(String name){
System.out.println("Hello "+name);}}


import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalculatorClass {
public static void calcInput(int fnum, int snum, int total){
    System.out.println("Give first number");
    Scanner firstNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
     fnum = firstNumber.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Give second number");
    Scanner secondNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
     snum = firstNumber.nextInt();
    total = fnum + snum;
    System.out.println("your total = " +total);

   }
 }
```

Comment: `calcInput` takes in three values but then you reassign them in the method, so figure out if you want to use the values passed to it, or get the values in the method itself.

Comment: @achAmháin I want to get the values from the method but i cant figure out how i can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You create an object of your Main. `Main main = new Main();`

But I suggest you should separate all your objects and functions properly. The proper way of creating classes and objects.

Then call it all in your main.